# Clojure: Java GUI Problem

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime

I have this little piece of code here.

```
(ns experiments
  (:import (javax.swing JFrame JLabel)))

(defn create-frame [title text]
  (doto (JFrame. title)
    (.add (JLabel. text))
    (.pack)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    (.setVisible true)))
```

Now I run a REPL (Clojure Box, basically emacs + slime), starting it with the right classpath and so on, call (use 'experiments) - which works - and then call

`(create-frame "Foo" "Bar")`.

Then... nothing. The REPL hangs up forever, no frame appears, nothing.

Comment: I just noticed I mistyped :import as import. I have it right in my copy.

Answer (score 2):

You should be talking to Swing from the event dispatch thread, for a start. Have a look at `clojure.contrib.swing-utils/do-swing`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me using Sun's JDK 1.6.0_26 and Clojure 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.04... However the window frame is very small because it is packed around a small "Bar" label. Are you sure you didn't miss it, and the window is actually nestling somewhere on your desktop?

Also, as I recollect (I might be wrong here), but I thought there were Swing issues with the  ubuntu-default IcedTea JRE - if you're using this, try the proper Sun/Oracle JRE instead.